# How can I limit the number of threads my binary tree creates?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

For each function that needs to go through every node, where order doesn't matter—like if you're trying to get it to count the number of nodes—I'd like it to do it in parallel.

I'm having issues limiting the number of threads that it creates. The basic structure is as follows:

```
volatile int threadLimit = 4, curThreads = 1;
mutex m;

void Tree::addThread() {
    m.lock();
    curThreads++;
    m.unlock();
}

void Tree::killThread() {
    m.lock();
    curThreads--;
    m.unlock();
}

Bool Tree::makeNewThread() {
    m.lock();
    Bool a = curThreads < threadLimit;
    m.unlock();
    return a;
}
```

Edit:

```
int Node::getCount() {
    if (!left || !right || !Tree->makeNewThread())
             irrelevant serial code
    else
            Tree->addThread();
            future<int> lf = async([this] () {return left->getCount();});
            int r = right->getCount();
            int l = lf.get();
            Tree->killThread();
            return r + l + 1;
    }
```

Edit (cont): The reason I want to do this is because it needs to go through every node. The particular system I'm using is an experimental version of a red black tree (I'm trying to add different ways to interface with it), and current stress tests show it can handle 2,000,000+ nodes (and theoretically up to 2^64). If it can go through these in several threads, then I'd rather do that.

For some reason, using this check method will make an infinite number of threads on my AMD desktop, but a limited number on my Intel laptop. Both are using the Visual Studios IDE and compiler, on Windows 8.1 (update), and the behavior was identical on 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: I see no code that limits the number of threads above.  No thread creation even.

Comment: Could you please show us how you are making the calls to these functions?

Comment: These aren't even valid C++. Your members claim no return types. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would go a long way to develop your question.

Comment: Why are you using threads in a binary tree?  Do you need a single thread that manages the tree (insertions, removals, traversals)?  In most cases, there is more overhead in creating and maintaining the thread than the help it provides.  The processes with a binary tree should be fast enough not to warrant a separate thread.

Comment: The `threadLimit` should be a `const unsigned int` since this value is not changing and it can't be negative (can you have -3 threads?).

Comment: Just added some explanations. As to the thread limit, it's grabbed as a multiple of thread::hardware_concurrency() (hope I remembered that name correctly), so it might not always be constant. If that would work, I'd be happy to change that.

Comment: I would suggest creating all the threads you want to have up front and never creating or destroying them during the normal execution of your program. This not only avoids the overhead of creating and destroying threads, but it ensures you'll have the number you want from beginning to end.

Comment: How would use do that in a way where it can still return values? All the guides I've seen haven't included that ability at all.

Comment: @gabeappleton You have an object that represents the job the thread does. The result goes in that object. In `c++11`, you can include a `std::function` in the job that's called by the thread to return the result. You can also use a `std::future`.

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the code? It looks like you never call `addThread`, so `curThreads` would always be 1.

Comment: I did have that. Problem is I was at school without the source code on hand, so I constructed it from memory. Looks like I forgot those two lines.

Comment: It's very odd though. For the failing machines (it's now 2:1, and no longer isolated to AMD), it says in the breakpoints that the relevant checking methods never get called. Yet the same source code on the working computer says they are.

Answer (score 0):

You might use posix semaphores http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview

You would initialize them to the number of threads that you want to have. You would use sem_wait() just before creating an new thread to limit them and use sem_post() just after a thread has terminated to increase the count of free threads again.

Comment: If this is Linux-specific then I can't use it. I'm trying to be general, and every machine available to me is windows anyhow.